# Can Jacksson handle enum

Tags: json, jackson

Say I have an enum.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Gender gender;
```

will jackson json parser be able to set this value from a json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. One way to verify this is to serialize POJO value, see what happens. By default, enum.name() is used as the serialization, expected for deserializing.